# css background-input and firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have some trouble with firefox

When I want to display a background inside input, it does not take in count, the position I want.

with the following code I wanted to place the input background on the right (98%), it works fine with chrome, but not as expected with firefox.

```
.accepted-input
  background: url(../images/nav/success-mini.png) !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-position-x: 98% !important;
    background-position-y: 50% !important;
}
```

below the rendering with firefox

[image]

And now with chrome

[image]

I've done some research but I did not found any issue.

Anykind of help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shorthand tested in Firefox, here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/z8ypG/)**</kbd>

```
.accepted-input {
  background: url(../images/nav/success-mini.png) 98% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Firefox does not support `background-position-x`, instead use the following style `background-position: 98% 50%`.